# Forms will not display correctly with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3, and everything seems to work fine. However, forms don't show correctly.

This is what it looks like on my web page.

[image]

It should look something similiar to this as shown in the documentation.

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the class 'form-control' on your select element?

```
<select class='form-control'>
<option>my option</option>
</select>
```

have a look at [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) specifically at the supported control's select element

Comment: Brilliant. I should have noticed that! Thank you.